# MYSQL WHILE LOOP CONTINUE is not recognized

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

i try to skip one condition in loop mysql, and it not work

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_2()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 INT;
    DECLARE res TEXT;
    SET v1 = 5;
    SET res = "ok ";
    loop_4: WHILE v1 > 0 DO
        IF (v1 = 4) THEN
            CONTINUE loop_4;
        END IF;
        SET res = CONCAT(res, ", ", v1);
        SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    END WHILE loop_4;
    SELECT res;
END;
```

i wait for result, like **"res: 5,3,2,1"** (4 is skipped), but mysql say the syntax is incorrect.

If I replace

> CONTINUE

with

> LEAVE

it work, but the result is not what I need

Comment: Seems like you want `ITERATE`? - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/iterate.html I beleive you'd still need to decrement though.

Comment: if `ITERATE` is skip current condition, i mean 4?

Comment: `ITERATE` is start loop again, from first value, i need to skip some value

Comment: As I mentioned, you still need to decrement `v1`.  See my answer.

Comment: do you can to modify my example (code), to help me understand, what it mean?

Comment: tnx, i try it now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ITERATE` is what you want. In a comment, you mentioned

> ITERATE is start loop again, from first value, i need to skip some value

That is NOT the case.  ITERATE is equivalent to the concept of continue. Your loop was "starting over" (really, running indefinitely) because originally you had:

```
 loop_4: WHILE v1 > 0 DO
        IF (v1 = 4) THEN
            CONTINUE loop_4;
        END IF;
        SET res = CONCAT(res, ", ", v1);
        SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    END WHILE loop_4;
```

Which says, when `v1` is 4, go back to `loop_4` - the value of `v1` here is unchanged, so it will infinitely return to `loop_4` with `v1=4` then enter that if and start over again. As this is a while loop, you need to decrement `v1` on your own inside the if, e.g.:

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE loop_2()
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE v1 INT;
    ->     DECLARE res TEXT;
    ->     SET v1 = 5;
    ->     SET res = "ok ";
    ->     loop_4: WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    ->         IF (v1 = 4) THEN
    ->              SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    ->              ITERATE loop_4;
    ->         END IF;
    ->         SET res = CONCAT(res, ", ", v1);
    ->         SET v1 = v1 - 1;
    ->     END WHILE loop_4;
    ->     SELECT res;
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call loop_2();
+-----------------+
| res             |
+-----------------+
| ok , 5, 3, 2, 1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but if condition is like `(var = "abc")`, action is same?